# Incorrect Parents name on ESTA

Tags: esta

My question is about the US Visa ESTA. Does anyone know if it matters if I  put my name under the section of parent on my ESTA? How do I edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

The only section you can't edit is your passport data, that requires a new ESTA, everything else can be changed at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/ ([source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1088/~/i-made-a-mistake-on-my-esta-application)). Changing the parent name could occur for various reasons, marriage is a common one but most countries have legal ways to change a name so this is not as big a deal as it seems.